# Система оценивания в опроснике

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qradiobutton

У меня есть почти готовое GUI приложение. В нем пользователь указывает путь к текстовому файлу с тестом. Мне нужно добавить систему оценивания.
В самом текстовом файле на первой строке должны быть ответы к тесту. \Количество вопросов ограничено 10.
В приложении есть 4 окна, на 3 окне появляется информация из файла (конечно кроме первой строки с ответами), который выбрал пользователь и 30 кнопок (по 3 варианта ответа на каждый вопрос).

Мне нужно сделать сравнение первой строки посимвольно и каждой из нажатых кнопок. 
Также мне нужно вывести результат в 4 - последнем окне.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel    
from newrules import Ui_Form as Ui_NewRules  
from form import Ui_Form as Ui_OpenTest 
from окно4 import Ui_Dialog as Ui_LastWindow 

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(763, 544)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235);\n"
                                 "")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 48, 711, 441))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.text_zagolovok = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.layoutWidget)
        self.text_zagolovok.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                          "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.text_zagolovok.setObjectName("text_zagolovok")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.text_zagolovok)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)

        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                        "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                        "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЕНЕРАТОР ТЕСТОВ"))
        self.text_zagolovok.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow",
                                               "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                               "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                               "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                               "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                               "<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:18pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
                                               "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt;\">Генератор тестов</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать тест"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить файл с тестом"))

class LastWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LastWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class OpenTest(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_OpenTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
class NewRules(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NewRules):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.write_file)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.start_test)
        
        self.all_f = None
        self.last_line = None
    def write_file(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open File',
            '',
            '*.txt'
        )
        if not fileName:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return

        file = open(fileName, "r", -1, "utf-8")
        self.last_line=file.read(10)
        self.all_f=file.read()
        file.close()

    def start_test(self):
        self.newRules = NewRules()
        self.newRules.push_btn_starttest.clicked.connect(self.open_test)
        self.newRules.show()
        self.hide()
    def open_test(self):
        self.openTest = OpenTest()
        self.openTest.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_test_clicked)
        self.openTest.label.setText(f'{self.all_f}')
        self.openTest.show()
        self.newRules.hide()
        self.form()
    def open_test_clicked(self):
        print(f'def open_test_clicked(self): \n{self.all_f}', self.last_line, self.second_answer)
    def form(self):
        self.openTest.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.window4)
    def window4(self):
        self.lastWindow = LastWindow()
        self.lastWindow.show()
        self.openTest.hide()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

3-е окно, в кот. находится текст теста и кнопки для выбора ответа - **form.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(715, 639)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 571, 621))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 540, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 90, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.layoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 140, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_2.setObjectName("layoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_7)
        self.radioButton_8 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName("radioButton_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_8)
        self.radioButton_9 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_9.setObjectName("radioButton_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_9)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.layoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 190, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName("layoutWidget_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.radioButton_10 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_10.setObjectName("radioButton_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_10)
        self.radioButton_11 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_11.setObjectName("radioButton_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_11)
        self.radioButton_12 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_12.setObjectName("radioButton_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_12)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.layoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 240, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_4.setObjectName("layoutWidget_4")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.radioButton_13 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_13.setObjectName("radioButton_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_13)
        self.radioButton_14 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_14.setObjectName("radioButton_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_14)
        self.radioButton_15 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_15.setObjectName("radioButton_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_15)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.layoutWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 290, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_5.setObjectName("layoutWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.radioButton_16 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_16.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_16.setObjectName("radioButton_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_16)
        self.radioButton_17 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_17.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_17.setObjectName("radioButton_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_17)
        self.radioButton_18 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_18.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_18.setObjectName("radioButton_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_18)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.layoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 340, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_6.setObjectName("layoutWidget_6")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.radioButton_19 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_19.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_19.setObjectName("radioButton_19")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_19)
        self.radioButton_20 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_20.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_20.setObjectName("radioButton_20")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_20)
        self.radioButton_21 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_21.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_21.setObjectName("radioButton_21")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_21)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        self.layoutWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 390, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_7.setObjectName("layoutWidget_7")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.radioButton_22 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_22.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_22.setObjectName("radioButton_22")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_22)
        self.radioButton_23 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_23.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_23.setObjectName("radioButton_23")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_23)
        self.radioButton_24 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_24.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_24.setObjectName("radioButton_24")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_24)
        self.verticalLayout_8.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_8)
        self.layoutWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 440, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_8.setObjectName("layoutWidget_8")
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.radioButton_25 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_25.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_25.setObjectName("radioButton_25")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_25)
        self.radioButton_26 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_26.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_26.setObjectName("radioButton_26")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_26)
        self.radioButton_27 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_27.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_27.setObjectName("radioButton_27")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_27)
        self.verticalLayout_9.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
        self.layoutWidget_9 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_9.setObjectName("layoutWidget_9")
        self.verticalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setObjectName("verticalLayout_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
        self.radioButton_28 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_28.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_28.setObjectName("radioButton_28")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_28)
        self.radioButton_29 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_29.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_29.setObjectName("radioButton_29")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_29)
        self.radioButton_30 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_30.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_30.setObjectName("radioButton_30")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_30)
        self.verticalLayout_10.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 40, 111, 41))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Завершить тест"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "№2"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "№3"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "№4"))
        self.radioButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "№5"))
        self.radioButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "№6"))
        self.radioButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_18.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "№7"))
        self.radioButton_19.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_20.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_21.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "№8"))
        self.radioButton_22.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_23.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_24.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "№9"))
        self.radioButton_25.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_26.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_27.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "№10"))
        self.radioButton_28.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_29.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_30.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "№1"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "У меня есть почти готовое GUI приложение" -  хорошо. "Мне нужно добавить систему оценивания" -  понятно. "В самом текстовом файле на первой строке должны быть ответы к тесту" -  пусть так. "Мне нужно сделать сравнение первой строки посимвольно и каждой из нажатых кнопок. Также мне нужно вывести результат в 4 - последнем окне." -  Ну, нужно - сделайте. А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: как сравнить первую строку из файла с нажатыми пользователем кнопками и вывести результат в последнее окно?

Comment: Т.е. вы даже не знаете как выводить значение переменной в окно, и как получать отклик, введенный пользователем??? Ну тогда вам надо начинать с изучения PyQt.  Можно по документации, но я бы советовал по книгам. Ну, например "Прохоренок Н. Python 3 и PyQt 5. Разработка приложений" За одно и Python подучите, что-бы не задавать вопрос типа "как сравнить строку".

Comment: @passant , просто flikky еще не научился задавать правильно вопросы и у "Прохоренок Н. Python 3 и PyQt 5. Разработка приложений" вы цельного решения этой задачи не найдете.

Comment: спасибо, я бы не задавал таких глупых вопросов и учил бы всю документацию самостоятельно, но у меня есть короткий срок, за который мне нужно сделать эту работу и все приходится изучать на ходу

Comment: flikky, я не говорил что ваш вопрос "глупый", я сказал что вы еще плохо формулируете вопросы. А то что вы делаете работу "на ходу", это не очень хорошо.

Comment: у меня есть еще один вопрос: Какие критерии оформления самого текстового файла должны быть, чтобы программа работала? Я запишу их во второе окно

Comment: flikky, я не понял ваш дополнительный вопрос, записать вопросы в предпоследнее окно, точно так как и записать их в последнее окно. Но  учтите, что окне, которое я проигнорировал, есть проблемы с радиокнопками.

Comment: не каждый текстовый файл подойдет для правильной работы этой программы. Допустим у меня есть текстовый файл, в нем 10 вопросов, после каждого вопроса идут три варианта ответа, каждый на новой строке. При этом программа не работает. Поэтому я и создал второе окно newrules, для того чтобы написать там критерии оформления текстового документа, чтобы приложение работало. Я прошу вас составить эти критерии

Comment: а также, если размещать варианты ответа сразу после вопроса( на одной строке), то попросту не хватит места и в 3-ем окне текст будет обрезан

Comment: flikky, СТОП. Вы написали: "В самом текстовом файле на первой строке должны быть ответы к тесту. Количество вопросов ограничено 10." - это и есть ваши критерии. Я так понял и реализовал логику исходу из этих посылов. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окно, которое вы создавали в классе `OpenTest()`,
я проигнорировал, потому что не понял зачем оно нужно.

Модули **q1496576_newrules.py** и **q1496576_form.py**
я взял с предыдущего вашего вопроса.

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel 
   
#from newrules import Ui_Form as Ui_NewRules              # + Ui_NewRules
#from form import Ui_Form as Ui_OpenTest                  # + Ui_OpenTest
from q1496576_newrules import Ui_Form as Ui_NewRules         # + Ui_NewRules
from q1496576_form import  Ui_Form as Ui_OpenTest            # + Ui_OpenTest

#from окно4 import Ui_Dialog as Ui_LastWindow
#from q1499914_4 import Ui_Form as Ui_LastWindow
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(715, 639)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 571, 621))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(216, 209, 235);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 540, 111, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 90, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_5)
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.radioButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.layoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 140, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_2.setObjectName("layoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_7)
        self.radioButton_8 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName("radioButton_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_8)
        self.radioButton_9 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.radioButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_9.setObjectName("radioButton_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.radioButton_9)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.layoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 190, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName("layoutWidget_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.radioButton_10 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_10.setObjectName("radioButton_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_10)
        self.radioButton_11 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_11.setObjectName("radioButton_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_11)
        self.radioButton_12 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.radioButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_12.setObjectName("radioButton_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_12)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.layoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 240, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_4.setObjectName("layoutWidget_4")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.radioButton_13 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_13.setObjectName("radioButton_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_13)
        self.radioButton_14 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_14.setObjectName("radioButton_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_14)
        self.radioButton_15 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.radioButton_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_15.setObjectName("radioButton_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButton_15)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.layoutWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 290, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_5.setObjectName("layoutWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.radioButton_16 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_16.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_16.setObjectName("radioButton_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_16)
        self.radioButton_17 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_17.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_17.setObjectName("radioButton_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_17)
        self.radioButton_18 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.radioButton_18.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_18.setObjectName("radioButton_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_18)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.layoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 340, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_6.setObjectName("layoutWidget_6")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.radioButton_19 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_19.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_19.setObjectName("radioButton_19")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_19)
        self.radioButton_20 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_20.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_20.setObjectName("radioButton_20")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_20)
        self.radioButton_21 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.radioButton_21.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_21.setObjectName("radioButton_21")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.radioButton_21)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        self.layoutWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 390, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_7.setObjectName("layoutWidget_7")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.radioButton_22 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_22.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_22.setObjectName("radioButton_22")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_22)
        self.radioButton_23 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_23.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_23.setObjectName("radioButton_23")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_23)
        self.radioButton_24 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.radioButton_24.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_24.setObjectName("radioButton_24")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.radioButton_24)
        self.verticalLayout_8.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_8)
        self.layoutWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 440, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_8.setObjectName("layoutWidget_8")
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName("verticalLayout_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.radioButton_25 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_25.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_25.setObjectName("radioButton_25")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_25)
        self.radioButton_26 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_26.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_26.setObjectName("radioButton_26")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_26)
        self.radioButton_27 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.radioButton_27.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_27.setObjectName("radioButton_27")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.radioButton_27)
        self.verticalLayout_9.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
        self.layoutWidget_9 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 111, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_9.setObjectName("layoutWidget_9")
        self.verticalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setObjectName("verticalLayout_10")
        
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
        self.radioButton_28 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_28.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_28.setObjectName("radioButton_28")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_28)
        self.radioButton_29 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_29.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_29.setObjectName("radioButton_29")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_29)
        self.radioButton_30 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.radioButton_30.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_30.setObjectName("radioButton_30")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.radioButton_30)
        self.verticalLayout_10.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)
        
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 40, 111, 41))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Завершить тест"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "№2"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "№3"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "№4"))
        self.radioButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "№5"))
        self.radioButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "№6"))
        self.radioButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_18.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "№7"))
        self.radioButton_19.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_20.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_21.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "№8"))
        self.radioButton_22.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_23.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_24.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "№9"))
        self.radioButton_25.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_26.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_27.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "№10"))
        self.radioButton_28.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_29.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_30.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "№1"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "А"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "В"))
```

!!! ВНИМАНИЕ !!! **Продолжение в следующем ответе.**

Answer (score 0):

!!! **Продолжение ...**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(763, 544)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 209, 235);\n"
                                 "")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 48, 711, 441))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.text_zagolovok = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.layoutWidget)
        self.text_zagolovok.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        self.text_zagolovok.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                          "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.text_zagolovok.setObjectName("text_zagolovok")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.text_zagolovok)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)

        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                        "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                        "color: rgb(16, 209, 235);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЕНЕРАТОР ТЕСТОВ"))
        self.text_zagolovok.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow",
                                               "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                               "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                               "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                               "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                               "<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:18pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
                                               "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt;\">Генератор тестов</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать тест"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить файл с тестом"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
#class LastWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LastWindow):
class LastWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):                     # !!! +++
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


#class OpenTest(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_OpenTest):
#    def __init__(self):
#        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)
 
 
class NewRules(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_NewRules):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.write_file)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.start_test)
        
#        self.all_f = None
#        self.last_line = None
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.answers  = None                                         # +++
        self.questions = None                                        # +++
        self.lastWindow = LastWindow()                               # +++
        self.lastWindow.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.finish_test) # +++
        self.rb_answers = {                                          # +++
            0: [self.lastWindow.radioButton,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_2,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_3],
            1: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_4,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_5,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_6],                
            2: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_7,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_8,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_9], 
            3: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_10,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_11,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_12], 
            4: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_13,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_14,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_15], 
            5: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_16,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_17,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_18], 
            6: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_19,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_20,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_21], 
            7: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_22,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_23,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_24], 
            8: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_25,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_26,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_27], 
            9: [self.lastWindow.radioButton_28,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_29,
                self.lastWindow.radioButton_30],                 
        }
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
    def write_file(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open File',
            '',
            '*.txt'
        )
        if not fileName:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return
            
        ''' НЕТ
        file = open(fileName, "r", -1, "utf-8")
        self.last_line=file.read(10)
        self.all_f=file.read()
        file.close()
        '''   
     
        with open(fileName, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f: 
            self.answers  = f.readline()
            self.questions = f.readlines()

    def start_test(self):
        if self.answers is None:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                None, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')
            return    
    
        self.newRules = NewRules()
        
#        self.newRules.push_btn_starttest.clicked.connect(self.open_test)
        self.newRules.push_btn_starttest.clicked.connect(self.window4)  # !!! +++      
        
        self.newRules.show()
        self.hide()

# --- vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        '''       
    def open_test(self):
        self.openTest = OpenTest()
        self.openTest.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_test_clicked)
        self.openTest.label.setText(f'{self.all_f}')
        self.openTest.show()
        self.newRules.hide()
        self.form()
        
    def open_test_clicked(self):
        print(f'open_test_clicked(): \n{self.all_f}', 
              self.last_line #, 
#              self.second_answer
              )

    def form(self):
        self.openTest.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.window4)
        '''
# --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def window4(self):
        if self.questions is None:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Добавте файл с тестом')        
            return     
        self.lastWindow.show()
        self.newRules.hide()

        self.lastWindow.label.clear()
        self.lastWindow.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('TimesNewRoman', 15))
        for line in self.questions:
            self.lastWindow.label.setText(self.lastWindow.label.text() + line)
        
    def finish_test(self):
        answers = self.answers.split()    
        #print(f'def finish_test(self): {answers}')
        
        self.lastWindow.label.clear()
        for i, q in enumerate(self.questions):
            #print(f'question: {i+1} -- {q}')
            answer = answers[i]
            
            rbs = self.rb_answers[i]
            rb_answer = '\tВы не отвечали на этот вопрос.\n'
            for j, rb in enumerate(rbs):
                if rb.isChecked():
                    if answer == str(j+1):
                        rb_answer = '\tОтвет правильный.\n'
                    else:
                        rb_answer = '\tОтвет НЕ правильный.\n'
                    break
            self.lastWindow.label.setText(
                self.lastWindow.label.text() + q + rb_answer)            
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**111.txt**

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
Вопрос  1 - А
Вопрос  2 - А
Вопрос  3 - А
Вопрос  4 - Б
Вопрос  5 - Б
Вопрос  6 - Б
Вопрос  7 - В
Вопрос  8 - В
Вопрос  9 - В
Вопрос 10 - В
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]